# Is it possible to checkout a public Github repository from enterprise repository with Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to checkout a public repository in my Github Actions workflow that runs in a repository that's hosted in Enterprise Github. I'm using PAT that's generated in my public Github account in order to authenticate.

My workflow step for checking out public repo looks like this:

```
  - name: Check out the public repository
         uses: actions/checkout@v3
         with:
           repository: public_org_name/public_git_repo_name
           token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
           github-server-url: https://github.com
```

I have an error saying it's bad credentials. The PAT's value generated in my public github account is the same as the value of my github secrets `PAT`.

Error logs:

```
Determining the default branch
  Retrieving the default branch name
  Bad credentials
  Waiting 14 seconds before trying again
  Retrieving the default branch name
  Bad credentials
  Waiting 19 seconds before trying again
  Retrieving the default branch name
  Error: Bad credentials
```

During git repo initialization in the logs I have:

```
 /bin/git remote add origin https://ENTEPRISE_GITHUB.COM/public_org_name/public_git_repo_name
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
https://github.com/public_org_name/public_git_repo_name
```

I also get this warning

```
Warning: Unexpected input(s) 'github-server-url', valid inputs are ['repository', 'ref', 'token', 'ssh-key', 'ssh-known-hosts', 'ssh-strict', 'persist-credentials', 'path', 'clean', 'fetch-depth', 'lfs', 'submodules', 'set-safe-directory']
```

github-server-url is legit argument, as seen in [docs](https:///https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage)

**Also**, it's worth mentioning that I can clone my public repo without any issues with `git clone`

example:

```
- name: Code Checkout
        run: |
          git clone https://username:${{ secrets.PAT }}@github.com/public_org_name/public_git_repo_name.git
```

Is the `bad credentials` error misleading? Am I not doing the checkout action the right way?

Answer (score 1):

"bad credentials" is misleading. The warning is the real issue...

Your warning is essentially telling you it doesn't know what to do with the `github-server-url`, so it doesn't know where to authenticate and thus the bad credentials error. My suspicion is that you are somehow using an older version of the action that doesn't yet include the `github-server-url` option.

Looking at the changelog, it was a fairly recent addition:
https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/v3.1.0/CHANGELOG.md#v310